# html form error internet explorer

Tags: php, html

I have a form with basic html and php which is a simple survey. When the user clicks submit. It's meant to open an email application and have the answers in the body of the email. Now this works on every browser except Internet Explorer.

Could someone help me as to why? I've looked around and can't find any explanation ( most of the people that will be using this use IE)

the form code:

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

  <form action="MAILTO:daniel-leads@...?subject=Survey Submission" method="post" enctype="text/plain">

    <div>
      <p align="center">
        <img src="Volkswagen-Logo.jpg" alt="myPic" height="213" width="410" />
        <img src="image006.jpg" alt="myPic" height="213" width="410" />
      </p>
    </div>
    <font face="Calibri">
    <p align="center"><font size="6"><b>Volkswagen After Sales Survey</b></font>
    </p>

    <br>
    <br>1. What is your perception of our pricing when maintaining your VW out of warranty?
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="question1" <?php if (isset($question1) && $question1=="Value for money " ) echo "checked";?>value="Value for money ">Value for money</input>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="question1" <?php if (isset($question1) && $question1=="Fair" ) echo "checked";?>value="Fair">Fair
    </input>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="question1" <?php if (isset($question1) && $question1=="Way out of my price range" ) echo "checked";?>value="Way out of my price range">Way out of my price range</input>
    <br>
    <br>2. What would motivate you to keep servicing your vehicle out of warranty with us? echo
    <br>
    <textarea name="question2" rows="10" cols="60">
      <?php echo $question2;?>
    </textarea>
    <br>
    <br>3. What expectations are we not meeting?
    <br>
    <textarea name="question3" rows="10" cols="60">
      <?php echo $question3;?>
    </textarea>
    <br>
    <br>4. What medium is most effective for you when learning about advertising specials or service advice?
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="question4" <?php if (isset($question4) && $question4=="Print media" ) echo "checked";?>value="Print media" >Print media</input>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="question4" <?php if (isset($question4) && $question4=="Word of mouth" ) echo "checked";?>value="Word of mouth" >Word of mouth</input>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="question4" <?php if (isset($question4) && $question4=="Facebook" ) echo "checked";?>value="Facebook" >Facebook</input>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="question4" <?php if (isset($question4) && $question4=="Radio" ) echo "checked";?>value="Radio" >Radio</input>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="question4" <?php if (isset($question4) && $question4=="E-Mail" ) echo "checked";?>value="E-Mail" >E-Mail</input>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="question4" <?php if (isset($question4) && $question4=="SMS" ) echo "checked";?>value="SMS" >SMS</input>
    <br>
    <br>5. Are you using other non-franchise service centres?
    <br>*if yes is there any other reason you would do so other then price?
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="question5" value="Yes" onchange="toggle(this.selected)" id="radioYes">Yes</input>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="question5" value="No" onchange="toggle(!this.selected)">No</input>
    <br>
    <textarea id="textarea" name="question5" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
    <br>
    <br>Customer service and retention is very important and we would love to keep you coming
    <br>back for longer so please put some thought into your comments or any idea’s you may have
    <br>to improve our business.
    <br>
    <br>Comment:
    <br>
    <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40">
      <?php echo $comment;?>
    </textarea>
    <br>Current Vehicle:
    <br>
    <textarea name="car" rows="1" cols="40">
      <?php echo $car;?>
    </textarea>
    <br>Current km's:
    <br>
    <textarea name="milage" rows="1" cols="40">
      <?php echo $milage;?>
    </textarea>
    <br>

    <input type="submit" value="Send" </input>
    <input type="reset" value="Reset">
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: check ie console.you will see errors

Comment: where do i check the console? @FastSnail

Comment: Hit F12 and go to the console tab

Comment: @eternal j https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg589530%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: You also have some script missing (function toggle)

Comment: @mplungjan please explain sir im still new to html and php

Comment: You have function toggle called in the onchange of the radios

Answer (score 2):

you missed "/>" at submit button...
   it would be like

```
<input type="submit" value="Send"/>
```